# What is the purpose of attribute keywords in Helm Chart's Chart.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have seen in many Helm Chart's Chart.yaml where developers provide keywords, as for example

```
keywords:
  - "http"
  - "https"
  - "web server"
```

What is the significance of providing these? Are these getting validated by something in Helm?
I tried to look out for reasons, but I did not get useful information, so posting here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `keywords` field specifies a list of keywords about the project. It helps user search charts based on keywords. For example, `helm search repo database` will bring up the charts which contain the `database` keyword such as `postgres`, `mariadb`, etc.

Search by keyword:

```sh
$ helm search repo database
NAME                            CHART VERSION   APP VERSION             DESCRIPTION                                       
stable/cockroachdb              3.0.8           19.2.5                  DEPRECATED -- CockroachDB is a scalable, surviv...
stable/couchdb                  2.3.0           2.3.1                   DEPRECATED A database featuring seamless multi-...
stable/dokuwiki                 6.0.11          0.20180422.201901061035 DEPRECATED DokuWiki is a standards-compliant, s...
stable/ignite                   1.2.2           2.7.6                   DEPRECATED - Apache Ignite is an open-source di...
stable/janusgraph               0.2.6           1.0                     DEPRECATED - Open source, scalable graph database.
stable/kubedb                   0.1.3           0.8.0-beta.2            DEPRECATED KubeDB by AppsCode - Making running ...
stable/mariadb                  7.3.14          10.3.22                 DEPRECATED Fast, reliable, scalable, and easy t...
stable/mediawiki                9.1.9           1.34.0                  DEPRECATED Extremely powerful, scalable softwar...
stable/mongodb                  7.8.10          4.2.4                   DEPRECATED NoSQL document-oriented database tha...
stable/mongodb-replicaset       3.17.2          3.6                     DEPRECATED - NoSQL document-oriented database t...
stable/mysql                    1.6.9           5.7.30                  DEPRECATED - Fast, reliable, scalable, and easy...
stable/mysqldump                2.6.2           2.4.1                   DEPRECATED! - A Helm chart to help backup MySQL...
stable/neo4j                    3.0.1           4.0.4                   DEPRECATED Neo4j is the world's leading graph d...
stable/pgadmin                  1.2.2           4.18.0                  pgAdmin is a web based administration tool for ...
stable/postgresql               8.6.4           11.7.0                  DEPRECATED Chart for PostgreSQL, an object-rela...
stable/prisma                   1.2.4           1.29.1                  DEPRECATED Prisma turns your database into a re...
stable/prometheus               11.12.1         2.20.1                  DEPRECATED Prometheus is a monitoring system an...
stable/rethinkdb                1.1.4           0.1.0                   DEPRECATED - The open-source database for the r...
stable/couchbase-operator       1.0.4           1.2.2                   DEPRECATED A Helm chart to deploy the Couchbase...
stable/hazelcast                3.3.2           4.0.1                   DEPRECATED Hazelcast IMDG is the most widely us...
stable/influxdb                 4.3.2           1.7.9                   DEPRECATED Scalable datastore for metrics, even...
stable/percona                  1.2.3           5.7.26                  DEPRECATED - free, fully compatible, enhanced, ...
stable/percona-xtradb-cluster   1.0.8           5.7.19                  DEPRECATED - free, fully compatible, enhanced, ...
stable/redis                    10.5.7          5.0.7                   DEPRECATED Open source, advanced key-value stor...
stable/redis-ha                 4.4.6           5.0.6                   DEPRECATED - Highly available Kubernetes implem...
```

Check whether the chart has that keyword:

```sh
$  helm show chart stable/mariadb
apiVersion: v1
appVersion: 10.3.22
deprecated: true
description: DEPRECATED Fast, reliable, scalable, and easy to use open-source relational database system. MariaDB Server is intended for mission-critical, heavy-load production systems as well as for embedding into mass-deployed software. Highly available MariaDB cluster.
home: https://mariadb.org
icon: https://bitnami.com/assets/stacks/mariadb/img/mariadb-stack-220x234.png
keywords:
- mariadb
- mysql
- database
- sql
- prometheus
name: mariadb
sources:
- https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb
- https://github.com/prometheus/mysqld_exporter
version: 7.3.14
```